# Is the sum of randomly chosen half of $n$ values approximately normal?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I have $n$ real numbers $x_1, \cdots, x_n$, and I randomly pick half of the $n$ numbers and denote by $X$ the summation of these $\frac{n}{2}$ values. I wonder if the random variable $X$ is approximately normal as $n$ grows large? My simulation indicates this but I really hope for a mathematical justification.

Just add some mild restriction on the values of $x_i$: suppose $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 0$ and $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^2_i = 1$. These are essentially normalizing and should WLOG.
In this case, $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \frac{n}{4}$.
Let us consider how close $$\frac{X-\mathbb{E}(X)}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)}} = \frac{2X}{\sqrt{n}}$$
is to standard normal.

---

What I have tried: let $z_i$ be the binary indicator such that $z_i = 1$ if $x_i$ is chosen. Thus, $X = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i z_i$. These $z_i$ follow a standard Bernoulli distribution but are negatively correlated with correlation $-\frac{1}{n-1}$. So standard central limit theorem does not apply. But the intuition is, as $n$ grows large, the correlation becomes weaker and weaker, and thus these $z_i$ are nearly independent.
It is tempting to use Stein's method to justify, but this appears too technical to me, and I wonder if any simpler tool is there.

Comment: Are there any further restrictions on $(x_n)$'s? The result is certainly false if $(x_n)$ is constant, and if this sounds too trivial, then I still suspect that carefully perturbing a constant sequence will also result in something contrary to your conjecture.

Comment: Well, suppose all $n$ of the random, variables are distributed identically with perfect correlation (e.g. all $n$ are guaranteed to be the same), then the sum of half of them won't be approximately normal. Is the idea to apply the condition that the central limit theorem applies?

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks! If $x_i$ are constant, $X$ is constant as well. In this case, can we regard $X$ as a degenerate Normal with variance zero?

Comment: @SangchulLee I feel that under some mild condition of $(x_i)$, $\frac{X-\mathbb{E}(X)}{\mathrm{Var}(X)}$ should be approximately standard normal. It is tempting to use Stein's method. But as a guy outside of the math field, Stein's method is too technical to me.

Comment: @SangchulLee For example, Section 3 of this note https://statweb.stanford.edu/~souravc/Lecture8.pdf gives a combinatorial CLT example. The problem seems to be similar at first glance.

Comment: @CadeReinberger Yeah, here the $(x_i)$ are fixed real numbers, and it's indeed a bit tricky when we consider scaling $n$. Let me try to add some restrictions on these values. As you said correctly, if $(x_i)$ themselves are instead random variables, the conjecture won't be true.

Comment: I adjusted the counter-example I constructed to work under the extra conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $y_i = 2^{-i}$ and $x_i = a_n(y_i - b_n)$ for all $i\geq 1$, where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are chosen to satisfy

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 = 1. $$

Now let $I$ be the random set chosen uniformly among the family of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of size $n/2$. If we set

\begin{align*}
X_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\mathbf{1}_{\{i \in I\}}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i\mathbf{1}_{\{i \in I\}},
\end{align*}

then it is clear that

$$ \frac{X_n - \mathbf{E}[X_n]}{\sqrt{\mathbf{Var}(X_n)}} = \frac{Y_n - \mathbf{E}[Y_n]}{\sqrt{\mathbf{Var}(Y_n)}}, $$

and so, it suffices to study whether $Y_n$ is approximately normal.

Now for each fixed $m$, we may write

$$ Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^{m} 2^{-i} \mathbf{1}_{\{i \in I\}} + \mathcal{O}(2^{-m}). $$

Moreover, the random variables $(\mathbf{1}_{\{i \in I\}})_{i=1}^{m}$ are $\operatorname{Ber}(\frac{1}{2})$, and their joint distribution converges to that of $m$ independent $\operatorname{Ber}(\frac{1}{2})$ variables as $n\to\infty$. Using this, it is not hard to prove that the distribution of $Y_n$ converges to the uniform distribution of $[0, 1]$. Then

$$ \frac{Y_n - \mathbf{E}[Y_n]}{\sqrt{\mathbf{Var}(Y_n)}}
\quad \xrightarrow[\text{in dist.}]{n\to\infty} \quad \operatorname{Uniform}(-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3}), $$

and so, CLT does not hold in this case.

I also included the probability histogram for $10^5$ samples from this $\frac{Y_n - \mathbf{E}[Y_n]}{\sqrt{\mathbf{Var}(Y_n)}}$ with $n = 1000$:

[image: probability histogram]

Comment: Thank you! Brillant! I also explored the literature. Section 2.1 of the paper (Theorem 1 there) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.04821.pdf also provides a sufficient condition for the CLT to be true.